# Omit 0 lag order in ACF plot

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, autocorrelation

How can I omit the zero lag order in an acf plot? See this picture:

[image]
generated by

```
dummy<-c(14,0.004,0.2,1,0.002,-3,-0.042,1.2,-1,1.3,2.1,4,3001,-2,0.3,2,3)
acf(dummy)
```

The high peak (which is logically 1) is destroying the plot, since the scaling is too big. I would like to omit the high peak at lag order 1, so that the scaling can be reduced to -0.2 up to 0.2 for example, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution is as follows:

```
# Create an "acf" object called z
z <- acf(dummy)
# Check class of the object
class(z)
# View attributes of the "acf" object
attributes(z)
# Use "acf" attribute to view the first 13 elements (1 = lag at 0)
z$acf[1:13]
# Get rid of the first element (i.e. lag 0)
z$acf[2:13]
# Plot the autocorrelation function without lag 0
plot(x$acf[2:13], 
     type="h", 
     main="Autocorrelation Function", 
     xlab="Lag",     
     ylab="ACF", 
     ylim=c(-0.2,0.2), # this sets the y scale to -0.2 to 0.2
     las=1,
     xaxt="n")
abline(h=0)
# Add labels to the x-axis
x <- c(1:12)
y <- c(1:12)
axis(1, at=x, labels=y)
```

So far, this answers the original question. After running the code you should see a plot like the one shown below.

[image]

With regard to adding significance bands to the autocorrelation function, it will first be necessary, in this case, to choose a larger scale on the y axis. Otherwise, the significant bands will be outside the range and we won't be able to see them.

For example:

```
# Plot the autocorrelation function without lag 0
plot(z$acf[2:13], 
     type="h", 
     main="Autocorrelation Function", 
     xlab="Lag",     
     ylab="ACF", 
     ylim=c(-1,1), # this sets the y scale to -1 to 1
     las=1,
     xaxt="n")
abline(h=0)
# Add labels to the x-axis
x <- c(1:12)
y <- c(1:12)
axis(1, at=x, labels=y)
# Add 5% critical levels
abline(h=c(2/sqrt(17),-2/sqrt(17)),lty=c(2,2))
```

Since you'd probably prefer to have Bartlett's approximations rather than those 5% critical values, you can do the following:

```
# Store length of dummy
n <- length(dummy)
# Create a vector to store Bartlett's standard errors
bart.error <- c() 
# Use a loop to calculate Bartlett's standard errors
for (k in 1:n) {
     ends <- k-1
     bart.error[k] <- ((1 + sum((2*z$acf[0:(ends)]^2)))^0.5)*(n^-0.5)
}
# Create upper bound of interval (two standard errors above zero)
upper.bart <- 2*bart.error[1:12]
# Create lower bound of interval (two standard errors below zero)
lower.bart <- 2*-bart.error[1:12]
# Add intervals based on Bartlett's approximations to ACF plot
lines(upper.bart, lty=2, col="red"); lines(lower.bart, lty=2, col="red")
```

After running the code, you should see something like the plot below. The black dashed lines are the 5% critical values and the red dashed lines is the interval based on Bartlett's standard errors.

[image]

I hope this answers all of your questions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, your answer is very appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

Use the `Acf` function from the `forecast` package.

Comment: can you also tell me the following: I not only want to see the acf, I want to have the values and the significane level (p values). The values I can get with $acf, but not if they are significant. How can I get a table/list containing these values? Is this also contained in the forecast package?

Comment: The 5% critical values are $\pm 2/\sqrt{T}$ where $T$ is the length of the series.

Comment: I don't understand why those critical values are added to the plot of the ACF. While they are fine for the PACF, surely they need to be replaced by Bartlett's appoximations for the ACF? To me this seems like an (easy) issue to be solved for both the acf() function and the Acf() function. To identify significant autocorrelation coefficients in R, I'd be wary about using acf() and Acf() without making some slight adjustments to the plot. If I'm mistaken, I'd like to know.

Comment: It depends on whether you are using the ACF to identify an MA model, or to test for white noise. Bartlett's limits are better for identifying a model, the default limits are appropriate for white noise tests.

Comment: @RobHyndman Thanks. I now recall reading that the estimated standard errors are sometimes __overstated__ when applying Bartlett's formula to the residual autocorrelation coeficients.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
suppose;

x = rnorm(100) ## A typical white noise process

plot(acf(x,plot=F)[1:20])
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Set the `xlim` and `ylim`. For example:

`acf(x,20,xlim(1,20),ylim(-0.2,0.5))`

Comment: Although the idea is a good one (`xlim` and `ylim` are parameters that `acf` passes on to `plot` and they will indeed limit the plotting window), this code is not even syntactically correct.  Following the two-line example in the question, `acf(dummy, 20, xlim=c(1,20), ylim=c(-0.2,0.5))` will work.